# Overlaying an image on a cube in three.js does not work

Tags: javascript, html, css, three.js

I'm trying to overlay an image on a cube, for this I asked to write the code chat gpt and blackbox, in both cases I get a black screen. I saved the code in the file test.html and tried to run it in the google chrome and opera gx browser, only a black screen was not displayed. Launching through creating a server on a node JS did not help.

***CHAT GPT:***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Three.js cube</title>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.132.2/build/three.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        body { margin: 0; }
        canvas { display: block; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="canvas-container"></div>

<script>
   
    const scene = new THREE.Scene();

    
    const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);
    camera.position.z = 5;

  
    const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    document.getElementById('canvas-container').appendChild(renderer.domElement);

   
    const textureLoader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
    const texture = textureLoader.load('C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\test.jpg');

    
    const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ map: texture });

    
    const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry();
    
    
    const cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
    scene.add(cube);

    
    let isDragging = false;
    let previousMousePosition = {
        x: 0,
        y: 0
    };
    function onMouseMove(event) {
        const deltaMove = {
            x: event.offsetX - previousMousePosition.x,
            y: event.offsetY - previousMousePosition.y
        };
        if (isDragging) {
            const deltaRotationQuaternion = new THREE.Quaternion()
                .setFromEuler(new THREE.Euler(
                    toRadians(deltaMove.y * 1),
                    toRadians(deltaMove.x * 1),
                    0,
                    'XYZ'
                ));
            cube.quaternion.multiplyQuaternions(deltaRotationQuaternion, cube.quaternion);
        }
        previousMousePosition = {
            x: event.offsetX,
            y: event.offsetY
        };
    }
    function onMouseDown(event) {
        isDragging = true;
        previousMousePosition = {
            x: event.offsetX,
            y: event.offsetY
        };
    }
    function onMouseUp() {
        isDragging = false;
    }
    document.addEventListener('mousedown', onMouseDown, false);
    document.addEventListener('mouseup', onMouseUp, false);
    document.addEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove, false);

    
    function toRadians(degrees) {
        return degrees * (Math.PI / 180);
    }

    
    function animate() {
        requestAnimationFrame(animate);
        renderer.render(scene, camera);
    }

    
    animate();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

`

***BLACKBOX AI:***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Three.js Image Rotation</title>
    <style>
      body {
        margin: 0;
      }
      canvas {
        display: block;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r128/three.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      // Set up the scene, camera, and renderer
      const scene = new THREE.Scene();
      const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);
      camera.position.z = 5;
      const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
      renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
      document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

      // Load the image and create the texture
      const loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
      const texture = loader.load('C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\test.jpg');

      // Create the mesh with the image as its texture
      const geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(1, 1);
      const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ map: texture, side: THREE.DoubleSide });
      const mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
      scene.add(mesh);

      // Add event listeners to detect hover and update the mesh's rotation
      function handleMouseMove(event) {
        const mouseX = (event.clientX / window.innerWidth) * 2 - 1;
        const mouseY = -(event.clientY / window.innerHeight) * 2 + 1;
        mesh.rotation.y = Math.atan2(mouseX, mouseY);
      }

      renderer.domElement.addEventListener('mousemove', handleMouseMove, false);

      // Add a render loop
      function animate() {
        requestAnimationFrame(animate);
        renderer.render(scene, camera);
      }

      animate();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I ran the code on multiple devices but still got a black screen

Comment: You are trying to link the texture from your harddrive. Try it with an image which is hosted on a webserver - instead of `const texture = loader.load('C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\test.jpg');` do something like `const texture = textureLoader.load('https://flagcdn.com/w160/aq.png');` .

Comment: @FiddlingAway That exactly I showed him in my post...

Answer (score 1):

If I had to guess, I suspect the texture path is wrong...

```html
<script type="importmap">
  {
    "imports": {
      "three": "https://unpkg.com/three@0.161.0/build/three.module.js",
      "three/addons/": "https://unpkg.com/three@0.161.0/examples/jsm/"
    }
  }
</script>
<div id="canvas-container"></div>
<script type="module">
import * as THREE from "three";

const scene = new THREE.Scene();

const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
  75,
  window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight,
  0.1,
  1000
);
camera.position.z = 2;

const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.getElementById("canvas-container").appendChild(renderer.domElement);

const textureLoader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
const texture = textureLoader.load(  "https://pixabay.com/get/gefe3a53651a7efc132c4c30d5ba86d19fb4f7e5c2cc5a4fb6db51aeac76f4be39457f4b70271b1cb3df2a69c69754bf9_640.jpg"
);

const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ map: texture });

const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry();

const cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
scene.add(cube);

let isDragging = false;
let previousMousePosition = {
  x: 0,
  y: 0,
};
function onMouseMove(event) {
  const deltaMove = {
    x: event.offsetX - previousMousePosition.x,
    y: event.offsetY - previousMousePosition.y,
  };
  if (isDragging) {
    const deltaRotationQuaternion = new THREE.Quaternion().setFromEuler(
      new THREE.Euler(
        toRadians(deltaMove.y * 1),
        toRadians(deltaMove.x * 1),
        0,
        "XYZ"
      )
    );
    cube.quaternion.multiplyQuaternions(
      deltaRotationQuaternion,
      cube.quaternion
    );
  }
  previousMousePosition = {
    x: event.offsetX,
    y: event.offsetY,
  };
}
function onMouseDown(event) {
  isDragging = true;
  previousMousePosition = {
    x: event.offsetX,
    y: event.offsetY,
  };
}
function onMouseUp() {
  isDragging = false;
}
document.addEventListener("mousedown", onMouseDown, false);
document.addEventListener("mouseup", onMouseUp, false);
document.addEventListener("mousemove", onMouseMove, false);

function toRadians(degrees) {
  return degrees * (Math.PI / 180);
}

function animate() {
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
animate();
</script>
```